# Replace word in text file and writing it to a new file in python

Tags: python, text, line

So I have a text file with the following content:

```
NUM,123
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,BACON
CAR
NUM,456
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,BURGER
CAR
NUM,789
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,SAUSAGE
CAR
```

I am replacing the word "BURGER" with "PIZZA"

```
with open('input.txt','r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(data):
        if '456' in line:
            field = ','.join(data[i+3].split(',')[1])
            field = field.replace(field,'PIZZA')
```

How do I write everything back into a new file so that in the new file it has:

```
NUM,123
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,BACON
CAR
NUM,456
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,PIZZA
CAR
NUM,789
FRUIT
DRINK
FOOD,SAUSAGE
CAR
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close, try the following:

```
with open('input.txt','r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

with open('output.txt','w') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(data):
        if '456' in line:
            fields = data[i+3].split(',')
            fields[-1] = 'PIZZA\n'
            data[i+3] = ','.join(fields)
        f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works with the code you already have. It just adds a line to update your data, and then the code to write it all out to a file:

```
# read the data
with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

# process data
for i, line in enumerate(data):
    if "456" in line:
        field = ','.join(data[i+3].split(',')[1])
        field = field.replace(field,'PIZZA')
        data[i+3] = '{},{}\n'.format(data[i+3].split(',')[0],field) # added 

# write data to file
with open('result.txt', 'w') as outfp: # to write out data 
    outfp.write(''.join(data))
```

Comment: +1, pretty similar to my approach but I think modifying the list `data`, and then writing it all at once is more clear than what I have.

Comment: @F.J .. thanks, the solutions would have to be somewhat similar. I could move that `for` loop out of the `with` since the data file has already been read. Probably better that way.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in append mode and replace the word.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a little bit safer because it won't break if there's less than three fields after a `'456'` line. It also avoids creating an intermediary list and just writes each input line directly to the output file.

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as infile:
        index = -1
        for line in infile:
            if index >= 0:
                index += 1
                if index == 3:
                    line = '%s,PIZZA\n' % line.rstrip().split(',')[0]
                    index = -1
            elif '456' in line:
                index = 0
            outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're only replacing one string by another, why processing line by line ? Something like that should work:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as target:
        target.write(f.readline().replace("BURGER","PIZZA"))
```